# Bulk Copy from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sqlbulkcopy

I have a requirement for a project to move data from SQL Server to Oracle in bulk mode. There is OracleBulkCopy from DataDirect and ODP .net but to use that I have to first convert the data reader from SQL server into a CSV file and then can export that using bulk copy.This is a very inefficient process and I was wondering if there is another way.We can't use Linked servers.

Comment: I can't remember what the Oracle equivalent to linked servers is.  Then I'd use SELECT INTO...

Answer (score 1):

IF you use SSIS you should be able to directly load data to an ORacle database withouthgoing through the step of creating a text file for the load. This assumes the Oracle database is availble in your network.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your sql server data to a flat file or a comma separated file. You can use that flat file as an external table in Oracle.

An other solution is to create a database link from Oracle to sql server and to do 'select .. from ssss@db_link'.

Answer (score 0):

What is your data volume ?

If its not too huge, then try using Access as a bridge between the two DBs.

In access, map the source SQLSERVER table, and the destination ORACLE table.

Read from source, and write into destination, using Access.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure HS and establish a connection from your ORA db to the sql server. Create a table or MV which will give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using SqlBulkCopy and some c# code works really well.

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/use-sqlbulkcopy-to-quickly-load-data-from-your-client-to-sql-server